# Cannot ssh to remote machine in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I upgraded to VSCode 1.36.0 a couple days ago, and I am not able to ssh into the remote machine since then. When I try to do so, the following error comes up:

flock: 99: Input/output error

Anyone can help to find a workaround for this?

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: Try `1.36.1` and see if it helps

Comment: just use `puTTY` meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was opened on VScode github repository:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76675

Someone suggested a solution which worked for few:

> Add "no_proxy=127.0.0.1,localhost" to ~/.wgetrc, this issue will not exist.

You should follow this thread to know when the issue was resolved

Comment: I am already aware of this thread, however I'm in a more critical need to have it solved sooner. I used the mentioned solution but it didn't work for me

Comment: did you checked out this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/895
I pretty sure the right place to follow your issue is over github, for more patches or updates.
Otherwise if you're problem is that critical I would just **downgrade** my VSCode enviroment

Comment: Reinstall from older version?
By the way, they closed both issues, did you try to update?